# divisor is equal to zero

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, divide-by-zero

i have the following data but in query i got the zero problem in division by zero. so i want the output as given below in two forms.

```
drop table t;

create table t (id number(9), val1 number(9), val2 number(9));
insert into t values (1,23,2);
insert into t values (2,0,4);
insert into t values (3,7,4);
insert into t values (4,0,3);
insert into t values (5,4,6);
```

select sqrt(val2*val1)/val1  from t ;

SQL> /
ERROR:
ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

expected reults

in two forms
first query
like this

```
        ID SQRT(VAL2*VAL1)/VAL1
---------- --------------------
         1           .294883912
         2                    0
         3           .755928946
         4                    0
         5           1.22474487
```

second query
like this

```
       ID SQRT(VAL2*VAL1)/VAL1
---------- --------------------
         1           .294883912
         3           .755928946
         5           1.22474487
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`select sqrt(val2*val1)/val1 from t where val1 != 0`;

That will avoid the rows where val1 is 0 and so will not cause the "divide by 0" error. This should give you the second format.

For the first format where you want to show the 0 in the output you can use a case statement in the where clause.

```
select id, 
case 
    when val1 = 0 then 0
    when val1 != 0 then sqrt(val2*val1)/val1
end
from t
```

Comment: Yes, you right . this is only example but indeed, the val1 i get it from another calculation. So, i don't know if it zero or not.

Comment: Because you donot know if it is zero or not, you are doing this check. In case it is zero you want to return zero, in case it is not, you use your sqrt and division and it will not cause a Divide by zero error.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using a DECODE and NVL. In DECODE (if/then/else) specify the logic with or without zero. If you want to use some other value instead, use NVL.

Decode example:

```
SELECT DECODE(val1, 0, NULL, sqrt(val2*val1)/val1)  from t;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In your Data insert `into t values (2,0,4);` val1 is 0 so it will not allow this to Divide with 0. so either you need to check first weather val1 is 0 or not then perform this.

Comment: the data already inserted for maybe 10000 records now , i want to show these data and substitute results of column that has zero by zero in first query and in second query ignore it.

Comment: i would recommend you to write a stored procedure . in which first check if val1 = 0 then return 0 else follow your query